# Related fields in odoo studio

Tags: odoo, odoo-server

I'm using odoo studio,and I want to get a value from the wizard, I created a new field in odoo studio and made the correct logic, just I need to include the value we input in wizard, but that value is available in a seperate model, so I want to include value from that model's field to my model's field, I tried this but no success.

I tried this.[My logic for including a field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAcjB.png)
[error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60pOc.png)

Comment: You used the `amount` variable which is not defined. You probably forgot to add `record.`

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the absence of the field 'amount' in the current model.
In order to resolve this error you would have to create a related field in the current model for amount and then try using that field in the dependency.

```
amount_rel = fields.Float(related='model_id.field_name')
```

then

```
record['x_studio_down_payment_1'] = record.amount_total_signed * record.amount_rel
```

Comment: But, I'm using odoo studio, so that's why, I need to do every thing from odoo studio